# Dynamically create/download style for Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

For Google Maps for Android I have a JSON file in RAW with map style.

Is it possible for me to dynamically download JSON while the application is running and use it?

```
mMap = googleMap
mMap.setMapStyle(
    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
        this, R.raw.mapstyle1
    )
)
```

I cannot dynamically create a RAW file

But I can't replace the JSON file either because the settings only get the style via the resourceId in RAW

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use public constructor [`MapStyleOptions(String json)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MapStyleOptions#public-constructor-summary) instead of fabric [`loadRawResourceStyle(Context clientContext, int resourceId)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MapStyleOptions#public-methods) method. Something like that:

```
...
StringBuilder mapStyleStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

// create you map style JSON
mapStyleStringBuilder.append("[");
mapStyleStringBuilder.append(" { "featureType": "all", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#242f3e" } ] },");
mapStyleStringBuilder.append("]");

// convert it to String
String dynamicallyCreatedStyleJson =  mapStyleStringBuilder.toString()

// and apply to map
mMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(dynamicallyCreatedStyleJson));
...
```